# Contador de victorias

Tags: python

```py
def EntrarDatos():
    NombreRival=(input('Digite el nombre del rival'))
    GolRival=int(input('Digiye los goles del equipo rival: '))
    GolesUnab=int(input('Digite los goles de la UNAB:'))
    Datos=GolRival,GolesUnab,NombreRival
    cont=0
    if GolesUnab>GolRival:
        cont+=1      
        print('El numero de veces que ha ganado es: ',cont)
    return Datos
```

Entrada

```
Digite el nombre del rival:Barcelona
Digite los goles del equipo rival: 2
Digite los goles de la UNAB:3
```

Salida

```
El numero de veces que ha ganado es:1
```

Cada vez que inserte nuevos datos este contador sume 1 si la condicion se cumple

Necesito que cada vez que `GolesUnab` sea mayor a rival se sume en un contador, pero no se acumula y no se como solucionarlo.

Comment: si tu sumas `cont+=1` se estará aculando el valor de `cont` el cual irá en incremento. Podrías explicar mejor lo que quieres y cual es el problema puntual que tienes?

Comment: Este elemento se guarda en una lista dentro de una lista y necesito que cada vez que a > b se acumule la cantidad de veces que pasa dentro de esta lista.

Comment: y los datos??? eso solo es lo que el `input()` muestra. Pero entendí a lo que te refieres

Comment: Y pues no entiendo por que no se acumula, gracias

Comment: la variable `cont` no esta declarada como `global` por lo que su valor solo existe en el *scope* de la función, por lo que no podrás usar su valor en otro lugar, tampoco retornas ese valor. El valor de `cont` solo existe dentro de la función!

Comment: Y como la declaro global?

Comment: Ahora te doy una respuesta

Comment: Y se necesito que tambien me de los perdidos y empatados, hago una funcion aparte o en este mismo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Como quieras, pero lo ideal es que cada función se encargue de una cosa específica

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126809/discussion-between-neaney12-and-christian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dije en mi comentario, una opción seria declarar la variable como `gloabl` de esta forma la variable podrá ser accedida desde cualquier parte, de lo contrario la definición de la variable `cont` solo existe en el *scope* de la función `EntrarDatos`, el código no cambia mucho, solo se define a `cont` como `global` y se coloca la asignación `cont=0` antes.

```py
cont=0
def EntrarDatos():
    global cont
    NombreRival=(input('Digite el nombre del rival'))
    GolRival=int(input('Digiye los goles del equipo rival: '))
    GolesUnab=int(input('Digite los goles de la UNAB:'))
    Datos=GolRival,GolesUnab,NombreRival
    if GolesUnab>GolRival:
        cont+=1      
        print('El numero de veces que ha ganado es: ',cont)
    return Datos
```

**probamos**

```py
for _ in range(3):
    dato = EntrarDatos()
    print(dato)
    print(cont)
```

**resultado**

```
Digite el nombre del rivalyop
Digiye los goles del equipo rival: 2
Digite los goles de la UNAB:3
El numero de veces que ha ganado es:  1
(2, 3, 'yop')
1
Digite el nombre del rivalyop
Digiye los goles del equipo rival: 2
Digite los goles de la UNAB:4
El numero de veces que ha ganado es:  2
(2, 4, 'yop')
2
Digite el nombre del rivaltu
Digiye los goles del equipo rival: 1
Digite los goles de la UNAB:3
El numero de veces que ha ganado es:  3
(1, 3, 'tu')
3
```

Esto funciona, pero algo interesante es que, si se cambia el rival igual se aumenta el contador, esto es por que el programa no identifica al rival, solo suma 1 al contador, nada mas. Para solucionar esto se podría usar diccionarios para guardar cada rival y su victoria.

```py
victorias = {"UNAB":{}}

def EntrarDatos():
    NombreRival=(input('Digite el nombre del rival'))
    GolRival=int(input('Digiye los goles del equipo rival: '))
    GolesUnab=int(input('Digite los goles de la UNAB:'))
    Datos=GolRival,GolesUnab,NombreRival
    if GolesUnab>GolRival:
        if NombreRival not in victorias["UNAB"].keys():
            victorias["UNAB"][NombreRival]=1 #creamos el rival con el valor de 1
        else:
            victorias["UNAB"][NombreRival]+=1 #sumamos 1 al rival
        print('El numero de veces que ha ganado es: ', victorias["UNAB"][NombreRival]) #obtenemos el numero del rival
    return Datos
```

**probamos**

```py
for _ in range(3):
    dato = EntrarDatos()
    print(dato)
    print(victorias["UNAB"]) #imprimimos el diccionario
```

**resultado**

```
Digite el nombre del rivalyop
Digiye los goles del equipo rival: 1
Digite los goles de la UNAB:3
El numero de veces que ha ganado es:  1
(1, 3, 'yop')
{'yop': 1}
Digite el nombre del rivaltu
Digiye los goles del equipo rival: 2
Digite los goles de la UNAB:4
El numero de veces que ha ganado es:  1
(2, 4, 'tu')
{'yop': 1, 'tu': 1}
Digite el nombre del rivalyop
Digiye los goles del equipo rival: 1
Digite los goles de la UNAB:4
El numero de veces que ha ganado es:  2
(1, 4, 'yop')
{'yop': 2, 'tu': 1}
```

Como vez aqui si podemos tener un contador para cada rival